# In mocha testing while calling asynchronous function how to avoid the timeout Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

In my node application I'm using mocha to test my code. While calling many asynchronous functions using mocha, I'm getting timeout error (`Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded.`). How can I resolve this?

```
var module = require('../lib/myModule');
var should = require('chai').should();

describe('Testing Module', function() {

    it('Save Data', function(done) {

        this.timeout(15000);

        var data = {
            a: 'aa',
            b: 'bb'
        };

        module.save(data, function(err, res) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            done();
        });

    });


    it('Get Data By Id', function(done) {

        var id = "28ca9";

        module.get(id, function(err, res) {

            console.log(res);
            should.not.exist(err);
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: is it an integration test? it's a lot of time for a test to run - maybe you should consider stubs - https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire might help you.

Comment: May I recommend using promises for asynchronous stuff and testing it then is a breeze with [Chai as promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

You can either set the timeout when running your test:

```
mocha --timeout 15000
```

Or you can set the timeout for each suite or each test programmatically:

```
describe('...', function(){
  this.timeout(15000);

  it('...', function(done){
    this.timeout(15000);
    setTimeout(done, 15000);
  });
});
```

For more info see the [docs](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts).

Comment: shorter version is ```-t```. if you use mocha-test to run mocha from grunt task, this is also supported in options object ```options:{timeout:15000}```.

Comment: For the `it` you must pass in the `done` like `setTimeout(done, 200);` as per the [docs](http://mochajs.org/#suite-specific-timeouts)

Comment: what if you're using co-wrap around your mocha tests to allow generator functions, then this timeout doesn't work

Comment: this works for me.. you can set timeout for independent suites that are running async

Comment: FYI: passing arrow functions to Mocha is discouraged. http://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

Comment: Arrow functions are not discouraged in the link above. It just says you just need to know what they do so you don't screw up when needing to access the context. I never need the context, as relying on timeouts are fragile, and all my tests run in a few ms, but I do come across the same issue when using sinon-test. Still use lambdas 99% of the time.

Comment: `TypeError: this.timeout is not a function` when using `"mocha": "^3.5.0"`

Comment: yes getting the same error as @JuniorM highlighted. Also calling done with async/await doesn't work. so not helpful answer for our case

Comment: @adi are you sure you are not using arrow functions? Regarding async/await it's in the docs so should work (and is the same thing as using promises). Sounds like another question though.

Comment: @JuniorM You can increase your test timeout by updating scripts in your package.json.  See Daniel Mbeyah answer below.

Comment: Please update the answer to use the form "it(...test).timeout(newTimeout)" since this is the one that works now.
Updating the timeout globally seems like a bad idea, since it can hide things. I would think you want to do it in a very targeted way.

Answer (score 88):

I find that the "solution" of just increasing the timeouts obscures what's really going on here, which is either

1. Your code and/or network calls are way too slow (should be sub 100 ms for a good user experience)
2. The assertions (tests) are failing and something is swallowing the errors before Mocha is able to act on them.

You usually encounter #2 when Mocha doesn't receive assertion errors from a callback. This is caused by some other code swallowing the exception further up the stack. *The right way of dealing with this is to fix the code and not swallow the error*.

**When external code swallows your errors**

In case it's a library function that you are unable to modify, you need to catch the assertion error and pass it onto Mocha yourself. You do this by wrapping your assertion callback in a try/catch block and pass any exceptions to the done handler.

```
it('should not fail', function (done) { // Pass reference here!

  i_swallow_errors(function (err, result) {
    try { // boilerplate to be able to get the assert failures
      assert.ok(true);
      assert.equal(result, 'bar');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
});
```

This boilerplate can of course be extracted into some utility function to make the test a little more pleasing to the eye:

```
it('should not fail', function (done) { // Pass reference here!
    i_swallow_errors(handleError(done, function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(result, 'bar');
    }));
});

// reusable boilerplate to be able to get the assert failures
function handleError(done, fn) {
    try { 
        fn();
        done();
    } catch (error) {
        done(error);
    }
}
```

**Speeding up network tests**

Other than that I suggest you pick up the advice on starting to use test stubs for network calls to make tests pass without having to rely on a functioning network. Using Mocha, Chai and Sinon the tests might look something like this

```
describe('api tests normally involving network calls', function() {

    beforeEach: function () {
        this.xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
        var requests = this.requests = [];

        this.xhr.onCreate = function (xhr) {
            requests.push(xhr);
        };
    },

    afterEach: function () {
        this.xhr.restore();
    }


    it("should fetch comments from server", function () {
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);
        assertEquals(1, this.requests.length);

        this.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                                 '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]');
        expect(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }])).to.be.true;
    });

});
```

See [Sinon's `nise` docs](https://github.com/sinonjs/nise) for more info.

Comment: I have a huge suite of tests and I just went through all the promises in my specs to make sure they're all calling `done()` at the end of the promise and I'm already mocking the network calls using Angular's `$httpBackend`, but no luck. Wrapping every single spec with a try-catch doesn't seem very pragmatic. Any other suggestions?  thanks!

Comment: @GustavoMatias You actually haven't mentioned what your problem is, just stated that this is not a solution to whatever you are having problems with. Please do elaborate :-) Are your tests not failing fast enough? Are they failing at times, but you would like to know why? Hard to guess what you intend to achieve.

Comment: hi @oligofren! that wasn't the best explanation indeed. There's a more detailed explanation of my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510048/angular-mocha-memory-leak?noredirect=1#comment56767589_34510048 thanks!

Comment: "In general, the cleanest way (but ugliest) way of dealing with this problem is to wrap your code with a try/catch and pass any exceptions to the done handler." No, this is not at all the cleanest way. Not by a long shot. The cleanest way is to write code that does not swallow exceptions. Every time I've seen someone complain that Mocha was not detecting a failed test, that was because there was something swallowing the exception. Adding a `try.... catch...` works *around* the bug in the code under test rather than *fix* it.

Comment: @Louis you might possibly be right about the whys here, but I am unable to verify it out of the blue. anyway, people have a problem with Mocha _seemingly_ being unable to catch some error, and this is a way of handling it. your given approach assumes that the code swallowing the error is not some library function or similar, in which case it would not be so easily solved.

Comment: @Louis I finally got around to updating the answer. Of course, you are right, and it was basically poor wording. I have now made the wording more explicit, to say that this behavior is caused by the code you are passing the callback into, not Mocha, and that this is the code that should be fixed. The utility function is just there for the cases where it is unfeasible to fix the underlying code (for some reason).

Comment: For integration tests, where things shouldn't be mocked (that's what functional tests do), I'm assuming the only alternative to "speeding up the network" is to increase the timeout.

Comment: That's right. Increasing timeouts is about your only option.

Answer (score 29):

**If you are using arrow functions:**

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  // do your testing
}).timeout(15000)
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I've put `.timeout(5000)` and I'm still getting a timeout error of 2000ms exceeded for that test.

Answer (score 8):

A little late but someone can use this in future...You can increase your test timeout by updating scripts in your package.json with the following:

`"scripts": {
     "test": "test --timeout 10000" //Adjust to a value you need
  }`

Run your tests using the command `test`

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was actually the describe function,
which when provided an arrow function, causes mocha to miss the 
timeout, and behave not consistently. (Using ES6)

since no promise was rejected I was getting this error all the time for different tests that were failing inside the describe block

so this how it looks when not working properly:

```
describe('test', () => { 
 assert(...)
})
```

and this works using the anonymous function

```
describe('test', function() { 
 assert(...)
})
```

Hope it helps someone, my configuration for the above:
(nodejs: 8.4.0, npm: 5.3.0, mocha: 3.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not sending the response back, so it was hanging. If you are using express make sure that res.send(data), res.json(data) or whatever the api method you wanna use is executed for the route you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to resolve/reject the promises used in the test cases, be it spies or stubs make sure they resolve/reject.