# Angular + Mocha memory leak

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, mocha.js

I'm getting the following error when running the entire suite of tests:

`timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

After some investigation, I found out to be a memory leak issue. Looking at some heap profiling snapshot, objects still seem to be referenced and not getting garbaged collected.

Anyone know a solution that would prevent it from happening? There's some options such as going through each one of my 1000ish specs and adding `afterEach` to do some clean up, but that seems like a lot of work.

Here's a sample layout of how most of my tests look like

```
describe('MyClassCtrl', function() {

  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, ctrl;
  ctrl = $rootScope = $httpBackend = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
    inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_, $stateParams) {
      var $scope;
      $stateParams.id = 1;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('MyClassCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    });
  });

  describe('#_getMyList', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET("/my/app/url").respond({
        my_list: [1, 2, 3]
      });
      ctrl._getMyList();
      $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    it('does this', function() {
      expect(ctrl.my_list).to.eql([1, 2, 3]);
    });
  });
});
```

Below are some profiling screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

I was able to trigger a memory leak by simply wrapping one of my `it` in a loop.

e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  it('does this', function() {
    expect(ctrl.my_list).to.eql([1, 2, 3]);
  });
}
```

In my tests, I set all objects within a container object and cleaned it up in an `afterEach` (like the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998442/angularjs-unit-testing-memory-leaks)) but no luck. Memory allocation still keep increasing on Chrome's Dev Timeline tool.

Thanks!

Comment: Is karma or mocha gathering some logs data for you? it might be the case when the result of tests is stored in the memory, try to set `logLevel: LOG_DISABLE` in config file just to see if there is any difference

Comment: @maurycy good point! unfortunately setting the log level as `LOG_DISABLE` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you run it with coverage? Frankly speaking after each suite file the memory should be cleared

Comment: ohh interesting! how exactly do I check whether I have that enabled or not? currently my karma config has only `reporters: ['spec']`, but even removing that doesn't help.

Comment: If you don't know it then you most likely don't run coverage as you need to explicitly set it up. Does the same thing happens to your application when you run it in browser or is it exclusively unit tests problem?

Comment: @maurycy only happening with when running the whole suite of tests. No issues with the app itself.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @oligofren unfortunately no. We did however, worked around it by switching to another headless browser; PhantomJS. Which IIRC have a higher memory allocation. Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: Unfortunately, finding a memory bug without access to the SUT is damn near impossible, unless something immediately pops out from the test setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you cleaning up your mocked http backend. I have no idea how it functions, but I would expect that all your requests and responses are being stored in memory. That would cause it to increase gradually, test by test.

If this was using Sinon I would expect that you would create a stub/spy before the tests and clean it up afterwards (or run it in a sandbox).

Try taking a heap snapshot before and after running a test and diff the snapshots to find which objects keep increasing in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this could be related to the [memory leak in Mocha that has been fixed recently](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/commit/33c825ba054fc4dfdf6e270ec8369dd4a28530e1). Make sure to update your local mocha to `2.4.5` or newer to get the fix and try running the test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ui-router leaks memory in unit tests. I added the following code in the run block of my application:

```
$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    var clearAllMembers = function(obj, depth) { // prevent infinite recursion because of circular references
        depth = depth || 0;
        if (depth > 10) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (typeof(obj[i]) == 'object') {
                    clearAllMembers(obj[i], ++depth);
                }
                if (obj) {
                    if (obj[i] && (obj[i] instanceof Array) && obj[i].length) {
                        obj[i].splice(0);
                    }
                    delete obj[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        clearAllMembers($stateRegistry); // ui-router 1.0+
        clearAllMembers($urlRouter);
        clearAllMembers($urlService); // ui-router 1.0+
        clearAllMembers($state);
    });
});
```

and the memory consumption in unit tests is 7-8 times smaller (I have around 350 states).