# Mocha - how to check if element exist after ajax call

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

How to check if select have some option in it after it has been updated by ajax function. My select component is like below

```
class Select extends React.component(){
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state.item=[]
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get(list)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({item:response.data})
            // reponse data ['america','singapore','vietnam']
        })
    }   
    render(){
        return(
            <select>
                this.state.item.map((i) => {
                    <option value="i">i</option>
                })
            </select>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is my try:

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import Select from 'Select'
describe('select list', () => {
    it('should have options', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Select />)
        wrapper.update()
        const actual = wrapper.find('option').length
        expect(actual).to.not.equal(0)
    })
})
```

What wrong with this is, I got var actual = 0. It supposes to be 3. So I guess I missing something with axios. What should I add to my spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GET` request might be still waiting for the response but mocha already has completed the test execution.

You could add a timeout and assert after a while and then call the `done()` callback when you are done with the test. Please take a look at the [mocha's](https://mochajs.org/) `asynchronous code` section.

```
describe('select list', () => {
    it('should have options', (done) => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Select />)
        wrapper.update()
        setTimeout(() => {      
            const actual = wrapper.find('option').length
            expect(actual).to.not.equal(0)
            done();
        }, 2000)
    })
})
```

I recommend you to check the [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) which allows you to mock request rather than sending an actual request to the server.

Comment: this will give me error `timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8452:9), <anonymous>:4371:19)`

Comment: You could decrease the timeout to 1500 and see or increase the mocha timeout as this question instructs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er.

Comment: decrease to 1500 works, thanks. Is there way that we don't need to use settimeout but still get the real result?

Comment: If you use axios-mock-adapter as I mentioned in the answer, you can just set the timeout value to 0 and still get the tests  to execute successfully.

Comment: can you give the example using the axios-mock-adapter?

Comment: Here you go: http://raathigesh.com/Mocking-HTTP-Requests-with-Axios-Mock-Adapter/