# how to iterate through each text field in selenium ?

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, chai

I have a list of text fields each having the same class names. This is the html code:

each text field has the same class name and I am trying to automate the fields by sending keys to each text field by using the sendKeys method in selenium. I am using JavaScript(chai,mocha,node) to run my automation.

```
             <div>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1">adad</textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1">adadad</textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
                 <textarea class="form-control textarea-multi" name="191_table_1"></textarea>
              </div>
```

This is what I tried. I tried to use findElements by className and iterate through of the className and then fill the each text field:

```
describe('complete text fields',function(){
        it('fill all the text fields',function(done){
            driver.findElements(By.css("input[type=\'form-control textarea-multi\']")).then(function(texts){
                console.log("got the list of texts");
                texts.forEach(function(textField){
                    console.log("sending keys for each of the text field");
                    textField.sendKeys("test");
                    count = Number(count) + 1;
                    console.log(count);
                    if(count === 6) {
                        done();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

but it fails with a time out error. (Error: Timeout of 15000ms exceeded.) Any help will be greatly appreciated Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
By.css(".form-control.textarea-multi")
By.xpath("//*[@class='form-control textarea-multi"]
```

Comment: I still get the same error. However, I tried to print the array size. And it appears to be zero. I tried both of your suggestions.                                   driver.findElements(By.By.xpath("//*[@class='form-control textarea-multi']"))