# Why am I keep getting Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded from Mocha on async?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, mocha.js

I am trying to start javascript testing on Selenium, but I am stucked at the start.

MochaJS never waits for the end of test, instead throwing after 2 seconds

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/pavel/code/gscc/test/test.js)
```

My code is

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
let assert = require('chai').assert;

describe('Test Suite', function() {
    it('should do', async function(done) {
        try {
        let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
        await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
        const title = await driver.getTitle();
        assert.equal(title, 'Google');
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } finally {
            await driver.quit();
        }
        done();
    })
})
```

Mocha says that I have unresolved promises in my code, but are there such?

Comment: There is a suggestion in the error/warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after investigating I will try to answer my own question as I solved it.

Firstly, the **Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded.** is a common issue and it is just that - timeout was exceeded, but tests didn't run (cause they need more time to run). It is documented on stackoverflow [pretty good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er?rq=1).

The next problem is that Mocha awaits promise or done function to finish the test. When I wrote

```
it('should do', async function(done) {
    try {
    let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    const title = await driver.getTitle();
    assert.equal(title, 'Google');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
    done();
})
```

It neither got the promise nor it got done, **cause it does not work with async/await mechanism**, only with standard promises.

So I removed done and also **removed try-catch block completely**, now it works at last!

The final code is

```
describe('Test Suite', function() {
    this.timeout(0);

    before(async function() {
        this.driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    });

    it('should do', async function() {
        await this.driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
        const title = await this.driver.getTitle();
        assert.equal(title, 'Google1121312213');
    })

    after(async function() {
        this.driver.quit();
    })
});
```